# How to list/access all the available audio input and output ports/channels of a USB soundcard from a particular PC

Tags: sound, alsa, soundcard, python-2.7

In Windows 7, I used to use **pymedia**, a python library, to list the available interfaces as well as use them for playing and recording audio. A typical query would look like this:

[image: sound]

Now, I'm no longer using Windows 7 as I have migrated to Ubuntu 16.04. So, I used ALSA commands to see the available audio interfaces. The following is the output of the same:

```
skrowten_hermit@PC-760:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: AD1984A Analog [AD1984A Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 2: AD1984A Alt Analog [AD1984A Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Eight [M-Track Eight], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
skrowten_hermit@PC-760:~$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: AD1984A Analog [AD1984A Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 2: AD1984A Alt Analog [AD1984A Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Eight [M-Track Eight], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

As we can see, my external soundcard M-Audio is listed as an ALSA card here, which means it is being detected properly. Now, as I read through ALSA related articles, I learnt about devices and then used ***-L*** to view the available devices as follows:

```
skrowten_hermit@PC-760:~$ aplay -L
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
sysdefault:CARD=Intel
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Analog
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
dmix:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=Intel,DEV=2
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Alt Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=Intel,DEV=2
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Alt Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=2
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Alt Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=Intel,DEV=2
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Alt Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=Eight
    M-Track Eight, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Eight,DEV=0
    M-Track Eight, USB Audio
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=Eight,DEV=0
    M-Track Eight, USB Audio
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=Eight,DEV=0
    M-Track Eight, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Eight,DEV=0
    M-Track Eight, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Eight,DEV=0
    M-Track Eight, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Eight,DEV=0
    M-Track Eight, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Eight,DEV=0
    M-Track Eight, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Eight,DEV=0
    M-Track Eight, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=Eight,DEV=0
    M-Track Eight, USB Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Eight,DEV=0
    M-Track Eight, USB Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Eight,DEV=0
    M-Track Eight, USB Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Eight,DEV=0
    M-Track Eight, USB Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
skrowten_hermit@PC-760:~$ arecord -L
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
sysdefault:CARD=Intel
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Analog
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
dmix:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=Intel,DEV=2
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Alt Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=Intel,DEV=2
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Alt Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=2
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Alt Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=Intel,DEV=2
    HDA Intel, AD1984A Alt Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=Eight
    M-Track Eight, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Eight,DEV=0
    M-Track Eight, USB Audio
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=Eight,DEV=0
    M-Track Eight, USB Audio
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=Eight,DEV=0
    M-Track Eight, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Eight,DEV=0
    M-Track Eight, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Eight,DEV=0
    M-Track Eight, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Eight,DEV=0
    M-Track Eight, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Eight,DEV=0
    M-Track Eight, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Eight,DEV=0
    M-Track Eight, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=Eight,DEV=0
    M-Track Eight, USB Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Eight,DEV=0
    M-Track Eight, USB Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Eight,DEV=0
    M-Track Eight, USB Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Eight,DEV=0
    M-Track Eight, USB Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

The above is a bit different from what I was expecting (I was hoping to get the channel identifiers, but instead ended up getting parameters like *sysdefault*, *front*, *surround21*, *dsnoop*, *hw* etc.). My sound card has Eight I/O pairs. So, I was expecting the channels/port identifiers or something like that.

After a bit more digging into the web, I stumbled upon **pyAudio** and **sounddevice** python libraries. The former gave the following output:

```
skrowten_hermit@PC-760:~$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyaudio
>>> p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1029:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1029:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot open PortAudio client
JackShmReadWritePtr1::~JackShmReadWritePtr1 - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock
>>> for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
...     print p.get_device_info_by_index(i).get('name')
...
HDA Intel: AD1984A Analog (hw:0,0)
HDA Intel: AD1984A Alt Analog (hw:0,2)
M-Track Eight: USB Audio (hw:1,0)
sysdefault
pulse
default
>>> import pyaudio
>>> p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
>>> for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
...     print p.get_device_info_by_index(i)
...
{'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.008707482993197279, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.008707482993197279, 'maxInputChannels': 2L, 'structVersion': 2L, 'hostApi': 0L, 'index': 0, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'maxOutputChannels': 2L, 'name': u'HDA Intel: AD1984A Analog (hw:0,0)', 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.034829931972789115}
{'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.008707482993197279, 'maxInputChannels': 2L, 'structVersion': 2L, 'hostApi': 0L, 'index': 1, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': -1.0, 'maxOutputChannels': 0L, 'name': u'HDA Intel: AD1984A Alt Analog (hw:0,2)', 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.034829931972789115}
{'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.008707482993197279, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.008707482993197279, 'maxInputChannels': 8L, 'structVersion': 2L, 'hostApi': 0L, 'index': 2, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'maxOutputChannels': 8L, 'name': u'M-Track Eight: USB Audio (hw:1,0)', 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.034829931972789115}
{'defaultSampleRate': 48000.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.021333333333333333, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.021333333333333333, 'maxInputChannels': 128L, 'structVersion': 2L, 'hostApi': 0L, 'index': 3, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.021333333333333333, 'maxOutputChannels': 128L, 'name': u'sysdefault', 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.021333333333333333}
{'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.008707482993197279, 'defaultLowInputLatency': -1.0, 'maxInputChannels': 0L, 'structVersion': 2L, 'hostApi': 0L, 'index': 4, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'maxOutputChannels': 2L, 'name': u'front', 'defaultHighInputLatency': -1.0}
{'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.008707482993197279, 'defaultLowInputLatency': -1.0, 'maxInputChannels': 0L, 'structVersion': 2L, 'hostApi': 0L, 'index': 5, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'maxOutputChannels': 2L, 'name': u'surround40', 'defaultHighInputLatency': -1.0}
{'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.008707482993197279, 'defaultLowInputLatency': -1.0, 'maxInputChannels': 0L, 'structVersion': 2L, 'hostApi': 0L, 'index': 6, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'maxOutputChannels': 2L, 'name': u'surround51', 'defaultHighInputLatency': -1.0}
{'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.008707482993197279, 'defaultLowInputLatency': -1.0, 'maxInputChannels': 0L, 'structVersion': 2L, 'hostApi': 0L, 'index': 7, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'maxOutputChannels': 2L, 'name': u'surround71', 'defaultHighInputLatency': -1.0}
{'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.008707482993197279, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.008707482993197279, 'maxInputChannels': 32L, 'structVersion': 2L, 'hostApi': 0L, 'index': 8, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'maxOutputChannels': 32L, 'name': u'pulse', 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.034829931972789115}
{'defaultSampleRate': 48000.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.021333333333333333, 'defaultLowInputLatency': -1.0, 'maxInputChannels': 0L, 'structVersion': 2L, 'hostApi': 0L, 'index': 9, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.021333333333333333, 'maxOutputChannels': 2L, 'name': u'dmix', 'defaultHighInputLatency': -1.0}
{'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.008707482993197279, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.008707482993197279, 'maxInputChannels': 32L, 'structVersion': 2L, 'hostApi': 0L, 'index': 10, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'maxOutputChannels': 32L, 'name': u'default', 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.034829931972789115}
```

The above too was not satisfying enough. A closer look at the enumerated output of the device list reveals that, the one corresponding to *'name': u'M-Track Eight: USB Audio (hw:1,0)'* does show that the number of input and output channels are 8, but listed as a single device. Then, next up, sounddevice gave me the following output:

```
skrowten_hermit@PC-760:~$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sounddevice as sd
>>> sd.query_devices()
   0 HDA Intel: AD1984A Analog (hw:0,0), ALSA (2 in, 2 out)
   1 HDA Intel: AD1984A Alt Analog (hw:0,2), ALSA (2 in, 0 out)
   2 M-Track Eight: USB Audio (hw:1,0), ALSA (8 in, 8 out)
   3 sysdefault, ALSA (128 in, 128 out)
   4 front, ALSA (0 in, 2 out)
   5 surround40, ALSA (0 in, 2 out)
   6 surround51, ALSA (0 in, 2 out)
   7 surround71, ALSA (0 in, 2 out)
   8 pulse, ALSA (32 in, 32 out)
   9 dmix, ALSA (0 in, 2 out)
* 10 default, ALSA (32 in, 32 out)
```

Here too, device 2 shows 8 in, 8 out.

What I don't understand is:

1. When **pyaudio** and **sounddevice** can see my soundcard as having 8 pairs of I/O channels, why aren't they listing them as separate devices?
2. And that ALSA doesn't even see that at all (which is the basic requirement for using ALSA commands *aplay* or *arecord*)?
3. Or even if my understanding that devices correspond to physical analog channels/ports, where I would connect devices, is correct?
4. Is this a limitation of the driver?

My requirements in a nutshell:

1. I should be able to play out audio to (any) input port(s) of my *M-Audio M-Track Eight* soundcard and record as well as play out audio from (any) output port(s) of my *M-Audio M-Track Eight* soundcard and play.
   [image: M-Audio M-Track Eight description]
2. I should be able to use ALSA commands to play and record as mentioned above.
3. I should be able to play and record in separate threads.

How can I achieve this? Can I get a clearer picture of ALSA and its role here? Any drivers available which can satisfy my requirements?

---

**UPDATE:**

I created the following `~/.asoundrc` from the inputs I recieved:

```
pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave {
       pcm "hw:1,0"
    }
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}

pcm_slave.eightchannels {
    pcm "hw:1,0"
    channels 8
    rate 44100
    buffer_size 4096
    period_size 2048
}

pcm.ch12 {
    type asym
    playback.pcm {
        type dshare
        ipc_key 1111
        slave eightchannels
        bindings [ 0 1 ]
    }
    capture.pcm {
        type dsnoop
        ipc_key 1111
        slave eightchannels
        bindings [ 0 1 ]
    }
    hint.description "M-Audio channels 1,2"
}
pcm.ch34 {
    type asym
    playback.pcm {
        type dshare
        ipc_key 2222
        slave eightchannels
        bindings [ 2 3 ]
    }
    capture.pcm {
        type dsnoop
        ipc_key 2222
        slave eightchannels
        bindings [ 2 3 ]
    }
    hint.description "M-Audio channels 3,4"
}
```

So, with the above configuration, when I try running `aplay`, the following is what I receive:

```
skrowten_hermit@PC-760:~$ aplay -D ch12 -c 1 -r 8000 male_8k.wav
Playing WAVE 'male_8k.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono
aplay: set_params:1233: Sample format non available
Available formats:
- S32_LE
```

Assuming it's a mismatch with the format as indicated, I tried passing the format as argument for `aplay` as below:

```
skrowten_hermit@PC-760:~$ aplay -D ch12 -c 1 -r 8000 -f S32_LE male_8k.wav
Warning: format is changed to S16_LE
Playing WAVE 'male_8k.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono
aplay: set_params:1233: Sample format non available
Available formats:
- S32_LE
```

Does this error have something to do with the PCM devices or the `.wav` file being played?

P.S : The `.!default`s were added later. Removing them makes no difference!

Comment: These device names identify not only the actual hardware device, but also how it is configured and how you want to access it. What, exactly, is the purpose of your list? What do you want to do with the entires?

Comment: I need means to control the playback and recording of audio streams. Ideally, I would like the access to the ports through which I can play and record audio files in runtime (executed using a python script).

Comment: What kind of audio streams?

Comment: Not music, just plain speech. So, stereo or mono doesn't matter.

Comment: Use the enumeration of whatever library you're using.

Comment: I just updated the post with complete enumeration of devices listed by **pyaudio** and my requirements in detail.

Comment: Are you familiar with JACK, the Jack Audio Connection Kit? It sounds to me like it should be rather perfect for your needs. As the name implies, it allows you to make connections like you would using cables. It has nice GUIs too.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad I've heard and read about JACK and PulseAudio (they are basically sound servers right?), but never used it. But I'm afraid that may not be of much help. Because, I'm not trying to replicate audio streams here and pass them between applications. I'm actually having physical ports and cables to deal with. Just that I dunno how to access them using ALSA, more specifically using `aplay` and `arecord`. Any idea how?

Comment: You can do stuff between applications, but you're dealing with sources and sinks, which can be inputs and outputs of any kind, apps or physical ports. JACK is usually preferred by musicians and others who do more advanced audio stuff. Perhaps you'll want to join #UbuntuStudio on Freenode. (chat). They know all about this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around a lot and experimenting with plugins, I was able to find a solution to the above problem. It was nothing but an extension of the above answer and the hints I got from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296378/8-independants-mono-channel-on-7-1-sound-card-but-possibility-to-play-sound-on). To start with, the following is the `.asoundrc` I used to get it working:

```
pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave {
       pcm "hw:1,0"
    }
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}

pcm_slave.m-audio_m-track_eight_1 {
    pcm "hw:1,0"
    channels 8
    rate 44100
    buffer_size 4096
    period_size 1024
}

pcm.outch1 {
    type dshare
    ipc_key 1111
    slave m-audio_m-track_eight_1
    bindings [ 0 ]
    hint.description "M-Audio M-Track Eight output/playback channel 1"
}

pcm.inch1 {
    type dsnoop
    ipc_key 1111
    slave m-audio_m-track_eight_1
    bindings [ 0 ]
    hint.description "M-Audio M-Track Eight input/capture channel 1"
}

pcm.outch2 {
    type dshare
    ipc_key 1111
    slave m-audio_m-track_eight_1
    bindings [ 1 ]
    hint.description "M-Audio M-Track Eight output/playback channel 2"
}

pcm.inch2 {
    type dsnoop
    ipc_key 1111
    slave m-audio_m-track_eight_1
    bindings [ 1 ]
    hint.description "M-Audio M-Track Eight input/capture channel 2"
}

pcm.outch3 {
    type dshare
    ipc_key 1111
    slave m-audio_m-track_eight_1
    bindings [ 2 ]
    hint.description "M-Audio M-Track Eight output/playback channel 3"
}

pcm.inch3 {
    type dsnoop
    ipc_key 1111
    slave m-audio_m-track_eight_1
    bindings [ 2 ]
    hint.description "M-Audio M-Track Eight input/capture channel 3"
}

pcm.outch4 {
    type dshare
    ipc_key 1111
    slave m-audio_m-track_eight_1
    bindings [ 3 ]
    hint.description "M-Audio M-Track Eight output/playback channel 4"
}

pcm.inch4 {
    type dsnoop
    ipc_key 1111
    slave m-audio_m-track_eight_1
    bindings [ 3 ]
    hint.description "M-Audio M-Track Eight input/capture channel 4"
}

pcm.outch5 {
    type dshare
    ipc_key 1111
    slave m-audio_m-track_eight_1
    bindings [ 4 ]
    hint.description "M-Audio M-Track Eight output/playback channel 5"
}

pcm.inch5 {
    type dsnoop
    ipc_key 1111
    slave m-audio_m-track_eight_1
    bindings [ 4 ]
    hint.description "M-Audio M-Track Eight input/capture channel 5"
}

pcm.outch6 {
    type dshare
    ipc_key 1111
    slave m-audio_m-track_eight_1
    bindings [ 5 ]
    hint.description "M-Audio M-Track Eight output/playback channel 6"
}

pcm.inch6 {
    type dsnoop
    ipc_key 1111
    slave m-audio_m-track_eight_1
    bindings [ 5 ]
    hint.description "M-Audio M-Track Eight input/capture channel 6"
}

pcm.outch7 {
    type dshare
    ipc_key 1111
    slave m-audio_m-track_eight_1
    bindings [ 6 ]
    hint.description "M-Audio M-Track Eight output/playback channel 7"
}

pcm.inch7 {
    type dsnoop
    ipc_key 1111
    slave m-audio_m-track_eight_1
    bindings [ 6 ]
    hint.description "M-Audio M-Track Eight input/capture channel 7"
}

pcm.outch8 {
    type dshare
    ipc_key 1111
    slave m-audio_m-track_eight_1
    bindings [ 7 ]
    hint.description "M-Audio M-Track Eight output/playback channel 8"
}

pcm.inch8 {
    type dsnoop
    ipc_key 1111
    slave m-audio_m-track_eight_1
    bindings [ 7 ]
    hint.description "M-Audio M-Track Eight input/capture channel 8"
}
```

I've tried to keep the whole thing simple. The ALSA commands `aplay` and `arecord`, which are command-line sound player and recorder respectively, then allowed me to do what was required, i.e, play a speech file as well as to play a speech file at one channel (connected to an analog output port) and record it with another mono channel (connected to an analog input port).

In order to test the configuration file, I used the following `aplay` command:

```
skrowten_hermit@PC-760:~$ aplay -D plug:outch1 -c 1 -r 8000 male_8k.wav
```

With the above, playback works just fine. Now, in order to get down to business, and to see if both playback and capture and working, the following was used:

```
skrowten_hermit@PC-760:~$ aplay -D plug:outch1 -c 1 -r 8000 /home/sreekanth/Downloads/male_8k.wav | arecord -D plug:inch2 -c 1 -r 8000 -d 10 /home/sreekanth/Downloads/out_12.wav
```

The above uses channel-1 (connected to analog output port 1 on my M-Audio M-Track Eight soundcard) to playing device and channel-2 (connected to analog input port 2 on my M-Audio M-Track Eight soundcard) as recording device. To use other devices, *outch1* can be replaced by any of *outch2*, *outch3*, *outch4*, *outch5*, *outch6*, *outch7*, *outch8* and *inch2* by any of *inch1*, *inch3*, *inch4*, *inch5*, *inch6*, *inch7*, *inch8* (in accordance with what was defined in `.asoundrc`).

It was a bit hard to find the right and well documented literature for ALSA. But, from my experience, it is the parameter `bindings` you need to tinker with in order to route audio from analog ports (possibly a client channel) to ALSA channels (slave channels defined as above in `.asoundrc`).

Comment: And here why I have totally given up in 2020. What a mess.

Answer (score 2):

The four pairs are not listed as separate devices because they are not separate devices. The M-Track Eight is a single device with eight channels.

It would be possible to create a bunch of virtual software devices that emulate four stereo pairs. To do this, add something like this to `/etc/asound.conf` or your `~/.asoundrc`:

```perl
pcm_slave.eightchannels {
    pcm "hw:Eight"
    channels 8
    rate 48000
    buffer_size 8192  # make these sizes smaller for lower latency
    period_size 2048
}

pcm.ch12 {
    type asym
    playback.pcm {
        type dshare
        ipc_key 2222      # some random number, but the same for the same slave
        slave eightchannels
        bindings [ 0 1 ]
    }
    capture.pcm {
        type dsnoop
        ipc_key 2222
        slave eightchannels
        bindings [ 0 1 ]
    }
    hint.description "M-Track channels 1,2"
}
pcm.ch34 {
    type asym
    playback.pcm {
        type dshare
        ipc_key 2222
        slave eightchannels
        bindings [ 2 3 ]
    }
    capture.pcm {
        type dsnoop
        ipc_key 2222
        slave eightchannels
        bindings [ 2 3 ]
    }
    hint.description "M-Track channels 3,4"
}
...
```

Comment: This sounds useful. My M-Audio M-Track Eight has Eight pairs of I/O (a total of 16 ports, 8 input and 8 output). Also, I would like to understand if:  
1. sample rate parameter `rate` is like an upper limit? (the default rate is described as '44100')  
2. I can use either type `share` or `dshare` if I'm not planning to use sound servers (like `PulseAudio` or `JACK` as of now? In case, I may want to use either of those in future, which is the most suitable one?  
3. there is a way to determine the optimum values for `buffer_size` and `period_size`?

Comment: Since I'm new to these concepts, it would be helpful if you could also: 
1. explain the significance of `ipc_key`, if they stand for some unique identifier?
2. confirm my understanding that `bindings` stand for the channel identifier (since the type `asym` makes the channel full duplex, can I assume pcm.ch12's `bindings` parameter's '0' points to 'channel-1' and 1 to 'channel-2')? In that case, why should we define '0' and '1' for both playback and capture?
3. explain that, though we have created channels with this, how is this mapped physically (to the analog ports on the soundcard)?

Comment: The rate is the rate you want to use. It would not be possible to change it after the first stream has started, so you have to decide on one. Don't use `share`. The `ipc_key` is needed to differentiate it from other `dshare`/`dmix`/`dsnoop` device (which you don't have). `bindings` routes client channels to slave channels. Input and output devices are completely distinct (`asym` is used so that you can use the same device name for both).

Comment: Increasing the buffer size reduces the risk of underruns, but increases the latency.

Comment: Tried the above, gave me a `aplay: set_params:1233: Sample format non available` error, which I have updated in the post. :(

Comment: Use `plug:ch12`, or add the plug plugin to the definitions.